# Delete all directories with mtime < 10 minutes ago from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a script which scans a top-level directory, and returns its contents (which are all directories themselves) => `$scan = scandir("$path");`. The nested directories I'm returning are continuously being created by an external Python script.

I would like to be able to exclude the sub-directories which were last modified less than 10 minutes ago. I don't want to remove the directories from memory (i.e. I don't want to use `rmdir()`), but I want to do basically the same thing as Python's `list.remove()` function. All I'd like is to be able to delete those elements from the array.

Is there a function that will do this?

Everything I've googled regarding this so far has given me a way to delete the directory from the server.

---

**EDIT**: Here's an example of the script:

ls.php

```
$path = $_GET['path'];
$regex=$_GET["regex"]; // just a string passed in which selects directories matching a naming convention

$scan = scandir($path);

foreach ($scan as $child) {
    if (is_dir("$path/$child")) {
        if (preg_match("/$regex/",$child)) {
            if (!preg_match("/^\./",$child)) {
                $nested[]=$child;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The current script I have is really pretty simple. The contents being returned are all directories (excluding ./ and ../), and I just want to know how I can remove the elements of the array which are directories modified less than 10 minutes ago.

Comment: Lets see an example of an array or your script that you are using to create the array.

Comment: @Rasclatt post has been edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use `filemtime()` and `strtotime()` to figure it out, something like:

```
# Assign now
$now = strtotime('now');
# Loop scanned directory
foreach ($scan as $child) {
    # Assign dir name
    $dir = $path.'/'.$child;
    # Not a directory, skip
    if(!is_dir($dir))
        continue;
    # Not match, skip
    if(!preg_match("/$regex/",$child))
        continue;
    # If dots, skip
    if(preg_match("/^\./",$child))
        continue;
    # Take now minus the last modified time of the file
    $diff = ($now - filemtime($dir));
    # See if the difference is more than 600 seconds (10 minutes)
    if($diff > 600)
        continue;
    # Assign if less than 10 minutes
    $nested[] = $child;
}
```

Comment: Oh man, I wasn't even thinking about initially excluding the files. Great idea! I'll get this implemented soon. Thanks so much!